# Bash regex match spanning multiple lines

Tags: regex, bash, if-statement

I'm trying to create a bash script that validates files. One of the requirements is that there has to be exactly one "2" in the file.

Here's my code at the moment:

```
regex1="[0-9b]*2[0-9b]*2[0-9b]*"

# This regex will match if there are at least two 2's in the file
if [[ ( $(cat "$file") =~ $regex1 ) ]]; then
    # stuff to do when there's more than 1 "2"
fi

#...


regex2="^[013456789b]*$"
# This regex will match if there are at least no 2's in the file
if [[ ( $(cat "$file") =~ $regex2 ) ]]; then
    # stuff to do when there are no 2's
fi
```

What I'm trying to do is match the following pieces:

```
654654654654
254654845845
845462888888
```

(because there are 2 2's in there, it should be matched)

```
987886546548
546546546848
654684546548
```

(because there are no 2's in there, it should be matched)

Any idea how I make it search all lines with the `=~` operator?

Comment: Why not simply use `grep`?

Comment: Well, yes, but AFAICT your requirements don't really *require* multiline regexes either.

Answer (score 3):

> I'm trying to create a bash script that validates files. One of the
>   requirements is that there has to be exactly one "2" in the file.

Try using `grep`

```
#!/bin/bash

file='input.txt'

n=$(grep -o '2' "$file" | wc -l)
# echo $n

if [[ $n -eq 1 ]]; then
  echo 'Valid'
else
  echo 'Invalid'
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
twocount=$(tr -dc '2' input.txt | wc -c)
if (( twocount != 1 ))
then
  # there was either no 2, or more than one 2
else
  # exactly one 2
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Using anchors as you've been, match a string of non-`2`s, a `2`, and another string of non-`2`s.

```
^[^2]*2[^2]*$
```

Answer (score 0):

Multiline regex match is indeed possible using `awk` with `null record separator`.

Consider below code:

```
awk '$0 ~ /^.*2.*2/ || $0 ~ /^[013456789]*$/' RS= file
654654654654
254654845845
845462888888
```

Take note of `RS=` which makes awk join multiple lines into single line `$0` until it hits a double newline.